# UIWebView does not refresh a PDF file located on my server in my iOS application after changes to the source document

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView loadRequest method to load a pdf file located in my server, on first time it is loaded instantly when loading with loadRequest method. Problem is I am changing data in my app and update that data on server so pdf get updated on server with server logic and in my app I am reloading UIWebView but does not reloading immediately I need to reload again and again then after 7 to 8 times reloading it gets refreshed. Can any one help me that what is wrong with my process?

Answer (score 1):

Your iOS Device may be caching the PDF document in order to save on requests to the server.

Try using:

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0
```

This will remove the cache from your UIWebView

Answer (score 1):

You should remove cache and cookies when the webView is on. Put this on viewDidLoad() :-

```
   NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    if let cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```